# How can I rename files in bulk based on their comma-separated contents in shell?

Tags: shell

I have hundreds of files suffixed with ".txt". The "txt" files contain "id[0-9]" in a column with delimiter "," from other columns. What I want is to extract the "id[0-9]" as the file name of the corresponding file automatically one by one, any ideas?

for example:  ben.txt ,cotains:

aa,bb,cc,id2233,kk

And many files like this.

Then how can I extract id2233 to replace ben.txt to id2233.txt using shell or other methods？

thanks.

Comment: You can do this by throwing `awk` out and using the right tool for the job. What you're proposing is akin to cutting down a giant California Redwood with a haddock :-) Look for `rename` or `prename`, these allow you to do mass renaming based on Perl regular expressions.

Comment: Your textual description is hard to understand. Please give sample lines for the input and output files.

Comment: Let me reiterate the warning that `awk` is the wrong tool for the job. You've got security vulnerabilities that are very difficult to avoid when using it which would be utterly mooted if your code were natively implemented in either cautiously-written shell *or* a language with a direct `rename()` call (Python, Perl, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Generate a script to rename files.

```
# old.names: generate files with old and new names
# new.names: 
# rename.sh: file with commands to rename

paste old.names new.names | awk '{o = $1; n = $2; print "mv", o, n}' > rename.sh

# if you like how rename.sh looks
sh rename.sh
```

A fancier version which tolerates spaces in the file names

```
paste old.names new.names | \
    awk -v FS='\t' \
    '{ o = $1
       n = $2
       print "mv --", w(o), w(n)          
     }
     function w(s) { return "'" s "'"} # wrap
    '
```

Comment: This isn't proof against malicious filenames; if someone ran (in bash or another shell with the `$''` extended quoting syntax) `touch $'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\''`, you wouldn't want to run *either* version of this code in that directory afterwards -- the extra single-quote you're adding in the `w` function would be evaded by the literal in the name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think you are joking. Following this logic `mv A B` is not a good answer to a question "How to rename file A to B?"

Comment: Not joking in the slightest. It's the difference between telling someone `select count(*) from students where firstname='Bobby'` is good practice, and telling someone they can use string concatenation (`print "select count(*) from students where firstname='" name "'`) to safely form that same query. One of those is perfectly fine, the other is [a major source of security bugs](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if this is the best way of doing this, but you could loop through all the files in the directory, pick out the "id" field, and issue a rename statement.  Here is one way:

```
  for oldf in ben*.txt
  do
    newf=""
    echo " "
    echo "Old file: $oldf"
    newf=`grep ",id" $oldf | sed "s/^.*\x2cid\([0-9]*\).*$/id\1.txt/" | head -1`
    echo "New file: $newf"
    if [ ! "$newf" ]; then 
       echo "No valid id found in $oldf.  Please correct before continuing."
       exit 1
    fi
    if [ -f $newf ]; then 
       echo "File exists with id found in $oldf.  Please correct before continuing."
       exit 2
    fi
    echo "rename $oldf $newf"
  done
  echo " "
```

**Note: this takes the first record with an "id" field and uses that.**

This does not assume any particular position for the "id" field and it will use any length number.  However, it does assume that ",id" precedes the id number.

*Oh, in this example, the rename command is being echoed to the terminal so it won't actually do anything except show you what it would do.  You'll need to remove the echo to have it actually do what you want.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Generating shell commands as strings (`echo "$oldf $newf"`) is insecure for the same reasons I gave in a comment on @slitvinov's answer. That said, you can fix this one fairly easily: `printf 'mv %q %q\n' "$oldf" "$newf"` will generate an `eval`-safe command to perform the rename (note that `rename` on UNIX is (1) nonstandard, and (2) has different usage from`mv`).

Comment: Also, you should redirect your logging and errors to stderr, rather than mixing them in with the output on stdout -- otherwise, if someone is redirecting their output to a file, they may miss the error logs entirely.

Comment: Good points, @Charles-Duffy.  Without any info about whether this was a specific set of files the OP generated, files uploaded by (potentially malicious) users, or files handed out as part of the classroom assignment, I decided to leave security up to the OP.  Probably good form to always use it, however.

Comment: As for error messages, I was focused on proof-of-concept rather than implementation.  Again, without knowing the context, all I can do is offer a basic idea of how it might work -- and at 3am, I didn't think about stderr.  8^)  Thanks for the suggestions, though!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a cautious implementation (won't overwrite existing files; won't move files outside the current directory; not prone to [shell injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection); uses only builtins, other than the `mv` command itself).

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt; do
  IFS=, read -r _ _ _ id _ <"$f" || continue
  [[ $id = */* ]] && continue ## refuse to move files outside this directory
  [[ $id = .* ]] && continue ## refuse to give files hidden names
  [[ -e $id.txt ]] && continue ## refuse to overwrite files that already exist
  [[ $f = "$id.txt" ]] && continue ## skip if name already matches destination
  mv -- "$f" "$id.txt"
done
```